# Load html section first before expensive section

Tags: reactjs

I have a time consuming loop for a table that is outputting around 300 cells with some custom computation on each, it takes 4-5 seconds to load which makes sense. So I want to display a loading modal whilst its doing this. However the modal only displays after the expensive loop finishes?

```html
const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if(loading){
      console.log(loading, "Loading has started")
    }   
}, [loading])


return(

<>
  <Modal show={loading}>Loading....</Modal>
  
  <a onClick={() => setLoading(true)}>Load more</a>
  
  // Expensive loop
  array.map(() => {
    // HMTL
    <div>
      ----
    </div>
  })
  
</>

)
```

I can see from console log that state for "loading" has been updated but the modal has yet to display, so Im assuming its waiting for the loop to finish (which I dont want). Is there way to get it to output the html for the modal first or am I missing a fundamental of React?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a slow computation you probably don't want to be doing it on each render, since components can render quite a few times.
Ideally you only want to render do those expensive calculations when the input data changes, which can be achieved by splitting the processing and rendering.

I'm not sure I completely understand how the loading part of this is working, but something like this example should help:

```html
const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [computedArray, setComputedArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    setComputedArray(array.map(//expensive loop here))
    setLoading(false)
}, [array])

useEffect(() => {
    if(loading){
      console.log(loading, "Loading has started")
    }   
}, [loading])


return(

<>
  <Modal show={loading}>Loading....</Modal>
  
  <a onClick={() => setLoading(true)}>Load more</a>
  
  // Cheap loop, turn data into markup
  computedArray.map(() => {
    // HTML
    <div>
      ----
    </div>
  })
  
</>

)
```

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned that theres other components inside the expensive array loop. But your saying I should compute them all inc html output outside this render?

Comment: @CerIs that depends how easy it is to split the expensive parts from the parts turning data to markup I'd normally convert it to html on every render but if that's not possible you should be OK precomputing it as long as your use Effect dependencies are correct

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `Modal` is from so answering from a general perspective:

Personally, I'd keep the array in state and update it in a separate function, and use the `&&` symbol to display the Loading element. This way you're keeping all of your logic regarding the expensive calculation and loading/unloading in one place.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

  const getExpensiveCalculation = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const resultOfExpensiveCalculation = await ... // something here
    // assuming result is a spreadable array too
    setArray([...array, ...resultOfExpensiveCalculation]);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {loading && <Modal>Loading....</Modal>}

      <a onClick={getExpensiveCalculation}>Load more</a>

      {array.map(element => (
        <div>
        ---
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```